# Method to report combination of 3 binary variables

Tags: r, combinatorics

I'm looking for pointers on analysing three binary variables and presenting the results numerically and graphically.

I have 3 binary dummy variables that indicate whether an observations contains valid readings for heart rate and/or breathing rate and/or activity data.  I'd like a way to report the number (proportion) of observations in in the subsets of {heart=0, breath=0, active=0 ... heart=1, breath=1, active=1}.  I've started creating another level of dummies for each combination (heart1resp0active0 etc.), but this feels inelegant.  I'd find this easy with two variables but am stumped with 3.  I'm working in R.  Didn't include a reprex as I don't have any code to fix :)

Thx in advance for any pointers.

[[image: Binary dummy variables for combination analysis1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm a ninny.  Venn Diagram was the very basic way to go with this *smh*